# Execute SQL Script Using Web Service c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in C# programming and still learning day after day. How do I create executesql web service to retrieve data?

SELECT ID, Function, Level, Type FROM Machines WHERE Type IN (2,10) AND Level > 1

webconfig:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=      
     ExternalDataSource;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True"    
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Under WebMethod Do I need to retrieve all fields in my SQL query?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Services;

namespace EmployeeRecs
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for Service1
  /// </summary>
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
 // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,   
  uncomment the following line. 
 // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {

           //Create new web method to get details
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetDetails(int ID, string Function,int Level,string Type)
    {
        return Details(firstName);

     }
 }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, is this a simple little project for you to learn with, or something to use for an actual web application? Normally, you'd have a data service layer with interfaces that query your database and have interfac definitions and dependency injection and stuff, but that's kinda overkill if you're just trying to learn to fill an adapter with ADO - here is a link to a basic tutorial for just data access http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson03

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the results.  Using `SqlDataReader` is the lowest practical level, but since you're just returning a string it's hard to give a practical example.  You can also use data frameworks like Entity Framework and Dapper that return _objects_ instead or raw data.

Comment: As I said before I am new on this technology and still got a lot learn.